# Transparent UITableViewCell flashing background when animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a `UIViewController` with a custom background color. On top of it there's a `UITableView` with `UITableViewCells` that are semi-transparent (white color with opacity 0.5).

The issue I'm blaming about and the one I'm banging my head against the wall is in iOS 7, when you have a `UITableViewCell` with semi-transparent background and you try to delete/insert/moving rows (so relying on an animation effect) the entire `UITableView` with its cells ***flashing*** for just 0.1 second and set cells background to a more transparent one. This is very annoying.

The only thing I'm doing is set the background color of `self.view` with:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.4 green:0.5 blue:0.7 alpha:1];
```

and set the background color of cells with:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.5];
}
```

Here's a gif showing you the problem:

[image]

And here's the super simple project: https://github.com/socksz/TransparentCellFlashing

Please help me to solve this ridicolous issue! :P

Comment: What is the background colour of your UITableView? If you have set one, try setting it to "clear" (or any colour of your choice) in your xib/storyboard. Normally in iOS7, it is set to "default", which is the cause for most of these issues.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't matter. I've tried to set the background color of `self.view` (which is the table view) to `[UIColor clearColor]` and also tried to embed the table view in a `UIView` (the main view of the view controller) and set the background color of this view to clear. Doesn't work.

Comment: Oh OK. Then you probably need to override setSelected() property of your UITableViewCell by subclassing it. Or at least use the backgroundView property instead of the backgroundColor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Create a subclass of UITableViewCell(Such as named: CustomCell), and override the method in CustomCell.m :

   ```
   - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
       self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
       if(self){
           // Initialization code
           [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
           UIView * bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
           [bgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.5]];
           [self addSubview:bgView];
       }
       return self;
   }
   ```
2. Remove willDisplayCell method in MasterViewController.m

   ```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.5];
   }
   ```
3. Change the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in MasterViewController.m

   ```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
       [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
       return cell;
   }
   ```
4. Change the cell's class type in storyboard
   [image]

Just have a try :D

[image]

Comment: I LOVE YOU! It works like a shining charm. Why we need to add a custom view as a background view? Maybe 'cause the `backgroundView` and `backgroundColor` properties of `UITableViewCell` works in that way and we can't do anything to change that behavior? Thanks man! PS: Also +1 for the GIF :-)

Comment: It works fine in iOS6 which we only set cell's backgroundView or backgroundColor.Actually,I'm not quite sure why the cells flashing while updating in iOS7... :D

Comment: Hey I am having exact same problem but I am not using storyboard.So can I do initWithCoder stuff in initWithFrame:cellReuseIdentifier??

Comment: If I addSubview to cell won't it come above the textLabel?As I am no t able to see my textLabel?

Comment: @user1010819 (1)initWithCoder will called by framework when a view  loaded by xib/storyboard.Don't call initWithCoder manually! (2)If you cann't see the label,you can call [self.view sendSubviewToBack: bgView] after addSubview:... Just have a try !

Comment: Thats what I did but couldn't solve the problem.Need to try more.ButI was having exact same problem except that I had a gradient for color which was decided on the basis of index of row.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, Joiningss. Helped me a lot. I have suggestion for a minor improvement however: If you replace `[self addSubview:bgView];` with `self.backgroundView = bgView` it will have the same effect but you can still access (and possibly change) the cell's background view anytime outside the cell's class.