# insertRowsAtIndexPaths animation whitening effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

I have table view that needs to expand for 1 element. When I call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` method to do that with `UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle` animation, my table view gets whitening effect while transitioning to new size. How can I disable that whitening effect.

For Example when table view have blue background colour, while animating to add element, that colour gets alpha component (lets say 0.6), and when animation is finished, that alpha component is turned back to 1. Same thing is happening when I call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` method.

EDIT:

Call of animation to delete rows:

```
[_menuTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:position+1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
```

Call of animation to add rows:

```
[_menuTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

video of unwanted animation: [whitening effect](http://screencast.com/t/svdg01Ri52)

Comment: Can u add some code? Video of your desire action?

Comment: I uploaded video of whitening efect.

Comment: Have u try to change the cell background? Ot the table view background?

Comment: The video is good. Did you say that you change the size of table view when insert and delete rows? To make thing simple, you'd better remove all the subview from the expended cell, just assign a specific background color.

Comment: I change size of tableview every time I open element. But when I disable that, and create static tableview, problem is still occurring. Colours of tableview cells, are created in cellForRowAtIndexPath method, and like size of table view, don't affect everything else.

Comment: Problem is within [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3] part. When I remove alpha component it works fine. But when alpha component is present it has that whitening effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transparent UITableViewCell flashing background when animating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459376/transparent-uitableviewcell-flashing-background-when-animating)

Comment: Check this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459376/transparent-uitableviewcell-flashing-background-when-animating